# OpenRasta on .Net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, rest, openrasta

I'm trying to setup OpenRasta with .Net 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005 and keep getting the following error

**'OpenRasta.Configuration.Fluent.IHas' does not contain a definition for 'ResourcesOfType'**

```
        using (OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual)
        {
            ResourceSpace.Has.ResourcesOfType<Home>()
                    .AtUri("/home")
                    .HandledBy<HomeHandler>()
                    .RenderedByAspx("~/Views/HomeView.aspx");
        }
```

I've noticed I couldn't add a **'using OpenRasta.Configuration.Web;'** since it's a non-existent namespace, is that the reason?

Is there an online tutorial for setting up OR with .net 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use OpenRasta with VS2005.

You need VS2008, target .net 2.0 in your application, and deploy to your server that only has .net 2.0 on it.

In other words, at development time you need vs2008, but provided you link to the dlls in the Program Files/OpenRasta/net-20/ you'll be able to deploy to a machine with only .net 2.0.